# Creating SMS templates in android?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, sms, smslib

can anyone please help me in finding a way that how can I create SMS templates and save them via coding…I am unable to figure out a way for this situation as I am new to android. Your kind help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You can create a database table for templates and an editText and an insert button. Write code for inserting template from edit text in table on button click. You can show the saved templates in a listView after fetching from table. You need to work around sqlite database for achieving this...